# Vue - Babylonjs: SceneLoader.Append not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a Scene with Vue-Babylonjs. Now I wanted load a .obj file into my existing scene. 
Here's my Code:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <canvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
</template>

export default {

  data: function() {
    return {
      scene: null,
      engine: null,
      canvas: null,
      mainCamera: null,

    };
  },
      methods: {
        init: function () {
          const _this = this
          this.canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas")
          this.engine = new BABYLON.Engine(this.canvas, true)
          this.scene = new BABYLON.Scene(this.engine)

          this.mainCamera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("ArcRotateCamera", 1.5, 1.3, 20, BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(), this.scene)
          this.scene.beforeRender = function () {

          }
          this.engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
            _this.scene.render()
          })
          BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("./", "test.obj", this.scene, function (scene) {

});


        },
mounted() {
    this.init()
}
}
```

I have my test.obj file in the same folder as my component. I get the following errors in my console:

> Babylon.js v4.0.3 - WebGL2 - Parallel shader compilation
>   babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled expression at line :
>    babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled expression
>   at line :  babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled expression
>   at line :  babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled expression
>   at line :  babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16
>   Unhandled expression at line :  babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled
>   expression at line : 
>   babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled expression at line :
>   Vue App babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled
>   expression at line :  babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled
>   expression at line :  babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled
>   expression at line : 
>   babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled expression at line :
>   
>   babylonjs.loaders.min.js?b234:16 Unhandled expression at line :

Maybe someone can explain what could be wrong here? I'm completly new to Babylonjs and not sure, weather I'm using it correctly...

Comment: Maybe you can try to reference babylon.max.js to get clearer error message? Also, do you see any 404? Maybe the file is not found?

Comment: Yes, I get a 404 Error in my network tab in dev tools. Do you have an idea why it is not found? The component and the file are both in the same folder...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a VUE developer